# Failed to resolve entry for package "resize-observer-polyfill" in react

Tags: reactjs, shopify

Getting error

> failed to resolve entry for package "resize-observer-polyfill

at the time of making build

[image]

Comment: Hey, may you share how looks package.json of resize-observer-polyfill in node_modules folder? Also may you share a content of node_modules/resize-observer-polyfill/dist?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.